Approximation of z-transform transfer function
It is common in control theory to approximate a transfer function neglecting the high order terms, in example,
a transfer function with two poles:
$$
  P=\frac{1}{(as+1)(bs+1)}=\frac{1}{abs^2+(a+b)s+1} 
$$
approximated by this
$$
 P_1=\frac{1}{(a+b)s+1} 
$$
with one pole in $ -1/(a+b) $ .
Now consider the corresponding discrete z-tranform of P applying Zero-order-hold:
$$
P_z=(1-z^{-1}) \mathcal{Z}\left(\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{P}{s}\right)_{t=kT}\right)=
\frac{(e^{-b_i T} b_i - e^{-a_i T}a_i + e^{-a_i T}e^{-b_i T}(a_i - b_i))z^{-2}+ (a_i - b_i + e^{-a_i T} b_i - a_ie^{-b_i T})z^{-1}}{e^{-a_i T}e^{-b_i T}(a_i - b_i)z^{-2}+(e^{-a_i T}+e^{-b_i T})(b_i-a_i)z^{-1} +a_i - b_i}
$$
with $ a_i=\frac{1}{a} \ \ b_i=\frac{1}{b} $. The result is
again a fractional polinomial. My question is, could there be a method to neglect the high order terms in a similar way of that in continuos to obtain a lower order z-transform tf like this:
$$ 
P_{z1}=\frac {z^{-1}}{d_0+d_1z^{-1} } $$
(a z-trasform of a one pole process). Thanks.

Perhaps you might consider a Padè Approximation.

Interesting. I can't say I've ever made an approximation like that without consideration of the effect on the dynamics. Therefore, to answer your question, I will place the following requirements for when such an approximation may be sufficiently accurate, regardless of whether we are considering the Laplace or z transform domain:

We are only considering when $s$ is sufficiently small, and there must not be more than one pole or zero located at $s=0$ (because a first order system cannot have a pole or zero multiplicity greater than one).
The system is not unstable (because otherwise it may make an unstable system appear stable).
All poles and zeros must be real (because a first order system cannot have complex poles and zeros unless coefficients are complex, which would make the response complex).

Based on requirement (1), the following approximation can be made that increases in accuracy as $s\to0$:
$$z^{-n}=e^{-nsT}\approx nz^{-1}-(n-1)$$
Where $n$ is an exponent and $T$ is the sample interval. Provided the aforementioned requirements are met, this can be used to provide a first order approximation for any z domain transfer function, and given that it becomes exact at $s=0$, it will provide the exact final value theorem result.
As an example, let's consider the following second order system:
$$H[z]=\frac{1}{(1-cz^{-1})(1-dz^{-1})}=\frac{1}{1-(c+d)z^{-1}+cdz^{-2}}$$
Where both $c$ and $d$ must have magnitudes less than or equal to one to satisfy requirement (2), both must be real to satisfy requirement (3), and they cannot both be equal to one to satisfy requirement (1).
It then follows that the transfer function is approximated as:
$$H[z]\approx\frac{1}{(1-cd)-(c+d-2cd)z^{-1}}$$
Here is a figure demonstrating the accuracy of this approximation about the unit circle (that is, the frequency response) for the particular example of when $c=0.1$ and $d=0.2$, which shows that the accuracy improves as the frequency approaches zero as expected:

The Matlab code that generated the above figure is:
c = 0.1;
d = 0.2;
w = linspace(0,pi)';
z = exp(1i*w);
H_exact = 1./(1-c*z.^-1)./(1-d*z.^-1);
H_approx = 1./((1-c*d)-(c+d-2*c*d)*z.^-1);

subplot(2,2,1); plot(w, abs([H_exact,H_approx])); xlabel('frequency (radians/sample)'); ylabel('amplitude');
legend({'exact','approx'},'location','southwest')
subplot(2,2,3); plot(w, angle([H_exact,H_approx])*180/pi); xlabel('frequency (radians/sample)'); ylabel('phase (degrees)');
subplot(2,2,[2,4]); plot([H_exact,H_approx]); title('Nyquist plot');


Very good, it is exactly what I need, thank you. I do not understand how you get the exponential approximation, I would be glad if you show me this clearly. Anyway I see the approximation as the taylor first order serie
$ y^n \approx 1+n(y-1) $ with $ y=z^{-1} $ .

I wish I could tell you that I derived the approximation in a single step using a first order Taylor series expansion of $z^{-n}$ about $z^{-1}=1$, as you wrote, but I did it in two steps, only realising in hindsight the simpler approach. Firstly, I noted that the relationship to the Laplace transform was $z=e^{sT}$ (see Z-transform Wikipedia page), then did the first order Taylor series expansion about $s=0$ giving $z^{-n}=e^{-nsT}\approx1-nsT$ and $z^{-1}=e^{-sT}\approx1-sT$, then solved these simultaneous equations to eliminate $sT$.

I've added a comment to my answer that this approach provides the exact final value theorem result, which was implied, but not explicit.

In the continuous domain you are actually using a first-order Taylor approximation of the denominator polynomial of $H(s)$ at $s=0$ (i.e., at DC). In discrete time, this corresponds to a first order approximation at $z=1$.
As mentioned in the other answers, such an approximation is only useful if the second-order system has real-valued poles.
Let's consider a second-order discrete-time system of the form suggested in Stephen's answer, i.e., a system with distinct real-valued poles and zeros at the origin:
$$H(z)=\frac{1}{1+a_1z^{-1}+a_2z^{-2}}=\frac{1}{D(z^{-1})}\tag{1}$$
with $a_1^2>4a_2$ (ensuring that there are two real-valued poles).
The first-order Taylor approximation of the denominator polynomial at $z^{-1}=1$ is
\begin{align*}
D(z^{-1}) &= 1+a_1z^{-1}+a_2z^{-2}\\&\approx D(1)+D'(1)(z^{-1}-1)\\&=1+a_1+a_2+(a_1+2a_2)(z^{-1}-1)\\&=1-a_2+(a_1+2a_2)z^{-1}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
where $D'(z^{-1})$ denotes the derivative of $D(z^{-1})$ (w.r.t. $z^{-1}$!). From $(2)$, the corresponding first-order approximation of $H(z)$ is
$$H_1(z)=\frac{1}{1-a_2+(a_1+2a_2)z^{-1}}\tag{3}$$
This is the same result as obtain in Stephen's answer, just derived in a slightly different way.
Another method is to compute a least squares approximation of the second-order system by a first-order system. This can be done in the time domain or in the frequency domain. A well-known method for the (approximate) computation of a least squares solution in the time domain is Prony's method.
Design Example:
We approximate a second-order filter of the form $(1)$ with $a_1=-0.3$ and $a_2=0.02$ (which is the same filter as in Stephen's answer). The solution $(3)$ is
$$H_1(z)=\frac{1}{0.98-0.26z^{-1}}\tag{4}$$
Using Prony's method, we obtain
$$H_1(z)=\frac{1}{1-0.2941176470588236\,z^{-1}}\tag{5}$$
We define the approximation error by
$$\epsilon=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\big|h[n]-h_1[n]\big|^2$$
with $h[n]$ and $h_1[n]$ denoting the impulse responses of the original second-order system and the approximating first-order system, respectively. The errors of the approximations given by $(4)$ and $(5)$ are $\epsilon=1.3\cdot 10^{-3}$ and $\epsilon=4.4\cdot 10^{-4}$, respectively.
This shows that with standard approximation techniques such as Prony's method, a relevant error measure (mean squared error) can be significantly reduced as compared to more ad-hoc methods. The most useful error measure depends of course on the application.

Thank, it is funny that I already implemented days ago a LSQ method with classical algorithms to achieve the approximant; I didn't know there where a method like the Proni's. I will evaluate about using it.
